Epilogue for `yargs` Commands
I'm writing a command-line application in TypeScript using yargs. I want to add an epilogue to the auto-generated help.  That works fine for the overall usage information but not for (sub)commands.  This is the relevant my code:
import yargs from 'yargs';

yargs(process.argv.slice(2))
    .command({
        command: 'whatever',
        describe: 'Do something',
        builder: (argv: yargs.Argv) => argv.options({}),
    })
    .help()
    .epilogue('Report bugs at ...')
    .parse();

If I just run the script with option --help but without a command, everything works fine:
$ node --import=tsx src/index.ts --help
index.ts [command]

Commands:
  zzzso.ts whatever  Do something

Options:
  --version  Show version number                                       [boolean]
  --help     Show help                                                 [boolean]

Report bugs at ...

But if I specify a command, there is no epilogue:
$ node --import=tsx src/index.ts whatever --help
index.ts whatever

Do something

Options:
  --version  Show version number                                       [boolean]
  --help     Show help                                                 [boolean]

Any idea how I can add the line "Report bugs at ..." also to the help output for the commands?

There is not support for a global epilog displayed for subcommands too.
You can specify the epilog for each subcommand yourself.
import yargsFactory from 'yargs/yargs';

const myEpilog = 'Report bugs at ...';

const yargs = yargsFactory(process.argv.slice(2))
   .epilogue(myEpilog)
   .help()
   .command({
      command: 'whatever',
      describe: 'Do something',
      builder: (y) => y.epilog(myEpilog),
   });

% node index.mjs whatever --help
index.mjs whatever

Do something

Options:
  --version  Show version number                                       [boolean]
  --help     Show help                                                 [boolean]

Report bugs at ...

